# Convergence of an Improper Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

This is a question from an old exam qualifier:

Show that the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx$ is convergent.

I first notice that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x^{2}) \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|) \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x)
\end{equation*}
where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x)$ diverges and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x^{2}) < \infty$.

Next, a quick check on Wolfram alpha suggests this [integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dcos%28x*log%7Cx%7C%29dx) will diverge.

Regardless, I attempt to explore the integral further to see if I can determine for myself whether or not the integral converges.

My attempt is to use integration by parts as done in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737199/does-this-improper-integral-converge):
Using,
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx + \int_{-1}^{1}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx + 
\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx
\end{equation*}

I find that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx &= 
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left|x\right|+1}{\log\left|x\right|+1}\cos(x\log\left|x\right|)dx \\
&= \frac{\sin(x\log\left|x\right|)}{\log\left|x\right|+1}\Big{\vert}_{1}^{\infty}
+ \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x\log\left|x\right|)}{x(\log\left|x\right|+1)^{2}}dx \\
&= 0 + \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x\log\left|x\right|)}{x(\log\left|x\right|+1)^{2}}dx
\end{alignat*}
From here, I am not sure how to determine whether this integral converges or diverges.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A direct comparison shows that the final integral is convergent, using the fact that $|\sin(x \log |x|) \le 1$; for we have

$$\int_1^{\infty} \left|\frac{\sin{x \log |x|}}{x (\log |x| + 1)^2}\right| dx \le \int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x (\log x + 1)^2} dx$$

Setting $u = \log x + 1$ and integrating, the right-hand integral is equal to $1$.

Comment: Thanks.  After applying your suggestion, it works out perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that.